# Swift String DrawInRect top margin

Tags: swift, string

I'm trying to layout some text that is being exported as a PDF.
I'm using drawInRect(rect, withAttributes) to draw the strings, however, I'm getting a gap between the top of the rectangle the text is being drawn in, and the actual text.
[Here's a screenshot, with the bounding rects stroke in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGgGS.png)

the goal is to have the 2 "1." be top aligned, but because of that gap I can't figure out how to do that...

Thanks!

Comment: How are you getting the size of `rect`?

Comment: @Grimxn I set it manually, but wether I make taller or shorter, it doesn't seem to affect the gap between the top of the Bounding Rect and the text...

Comment: Have you investigated using the `String` function `let textSize: CGRect = str.size(attributes: attributes)`? I'm not sure if it will help, but it's where I would start...